# How to establish Cosmos DB database connection with nestjs v^9.0.0

Tags: typescript, nestjs, azure-cosmosdb, node-modules, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to import the Cosmos DB connection module in nestjs v9, but I'm getting dependencies errors.

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AzureCosmosDbCoreModule (COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_NAME, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the AzureCosmosDbCoreModule context. 

    Potential solutions:
    - If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current AzureCosmosDbCoreModule?
    - If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AzureCosmosDbCoreModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
      })
```

If I lower nestjs to version 8, the connection module works fine, I use this same code with both projects:

```
import { AzureCosmosDbModule } from '@nestjs/azure-database';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'; 
import { AppConfigModule } from '../shared/config/app-config.module'; 
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AppConfigModule, 
    AzureCosmosDbModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [AppConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (cfg: AppConfigModule) => ({
        endpoint: cfg.get<string>('AZURE_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT'),
        dbName: cfg.get<string>('AZURE_COSMOS_DB_TEST_NAME'),
        key: cfg.get<string>('AZURE_COSMOS_DB_KEY'),
      }),
      inject: [AppConfigModule],
    }), 
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
 
export class AppModule {}
```

project info (don't work): Node v16.16.0

```
    "@azure/cosmos": "^3.17.0", 
    "@nestjs/azure-database": "^2.3.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0", 
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
```

project info (works): Node v16.16.0

```
    "@nestjs/azure-database": "^2.3.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
```

Comment: Isn't the one that is not working missing the `@azure/cosmos` dependency?

Comment: I tested with "@azure/cosmos": "^3.17.0" and it still not working

Comment: can you try updating to 3.17.1 and let me know what happens

Comment: The same error  Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AzureCosmosDbCoreModule

Comment: I remember seeing this error too. Have you compared the _exact_ versions of the listed packages in both working and non-working case? You can do that by inspecting the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: The only change that I see in the package.json are the nestjs peer dependencies version 8 working and v9 non-working  no more

Comment: I have installed a blank project with version 9 and I only installed the azure module, it does not work with this version of nest I think I will create a module with the connection manually and inject it

Comment: I see the issue with `^9.0.0` as well. After lowering version to `^8.0.0` it started working.

Comment: Having same issue, even after updating nestjs to '9.1.2'

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the error by adding overrides to my `package.json`:

```json
"overrides": {
    "@nestjs/azure-database": {
        "@nestjs/common": "^9.1.4",
        "@nestjs/core": "^9.1.4"
    }
}
```

You may need to delete node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstall.

I'm not sure if anything else is broken on v9.